# I'm having problems looping a function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

[funtion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Su96.png)

I have been trying too loop the "1 + 1/3 + 1/5 + ... + 1/n" part in the screenshot inside my code but could not do it all.

The compiler calculates 'x' which is the factorial correctly the only problem for me now is looping the fractions in the function.

```
int main()
{
int i=1,n,x=1;  //x : factorial
double f;

cout<<"Enter an odd number : "<<endl;
cin>>n;

if (n%2==0)
{
    cout<<"You have to enter an odd number."<<endl;
}
else
{
    while(i<=n)
    {
        x = x * i;
        f = x*(1+(1.0/n)) ;
        i+=1;
    }
}
cout<<"f = "<<f<<endl;}
```

Comment: You are doing integer division. `1/n` should be `1.0/n`.

Comment: @MikeCAT Yeah I just corrected that but, I still want it to calculate the fractions, so for example if I enter the number 9, the code should calculate : 

f = 9! (1+ 1/3 + 1/5 + 1/7 + 1/9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    double f = 1;
    cout<<"Enter an odd number : "<<endl;
    cin >> n;

    if ( n%2 == 1)
    {
        double temp = n;

        while ( temp > 1 ) // this one calculates factorial, 
        {
            f *= temp;
            temp--;
        } // f = n!

        temp = 1;
        double result = 0;
        while ( temp <= n ) // this one calculates (1 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n)
            {
                result += ( 1 / temp );
                temp += 2;
            }   // result = (1 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n)

        f = f * result; // f = n! * (1 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n)

        cout<<"f = "<<f<<endl;
    }       
    else
        cout<<"You have to enter an odd number."<<endl;


    return 0;
}
```

You need to operate on the same types of data ;)

Comment: you can also do this in only one "while" it's easy, you should take a look at it and make it easier and shorter :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hey I have Modified your code, you can run it and can match your Result with Calulator**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
int odnumber(int num);
int calFactorial(int num);
int main() {
    int oddNumber, i = 1;
    float temp=0, temp2 = 0, f = 0.0;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter the Odd Number: " << endl;
        cin >> oddNumber;

    } while (oddNumber%2 == 0);
    while (i <= oddNumber)
    {
        if (odnumber(i))
        {
            temp = (double)(1.0/i);
            temp2 +=temp;
        }
        i++;   
    }
    f = calFactorial(oddNumber)*temp2;
    cout << "F is  = " << f << endl;
    return 0;
}
int odnumber(int num) {
    if (num % 2 != 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
int calFactorial(int num) {
    int x = 1, i = 1;  //x is Factorial
    while (i <= num)
    {
        x = x * i;
        i++;
    }
    return x;
}
```

[This is the Output: Run on my Machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdogd.jpg)